# Javascript find keys for the matched values as like query in SQL

Tags: javascript, json, search, key-value, sql-like

I want to use JavaScript to find keys for the matched values as like query in SQL. 
Suppose I've following json data:

```
{"100":"Jaipur","101":"Delhi","102":"Raipur","104":"Goa"}
```

If INPUT:

```
"pur"
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
{"100":"Jaipur","102":"Raipur"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for-in` loop to iterate through `object`. If `indexOf` searched string in target string is greater than `-1`, search value is present in the string.

Try this:

```js
var input = {
  "100": "Jaipur",
  "101": "Delhi",
  "102": "Raipur",
  "104": "Goa"
};
var needle = "pur";
var op = {};
for (var i in input) {
  if (input[i].indexOf(needle) > -1) {
    op[i] = input[i];
  }
}
console.log(op);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small function, maybe it helps you

```
var data = {"100":"Jaipur","101":"Delhi","102":"Raipur","104":"Goa"};

function search(data, text){
  var items = {};
   for(var i in data){
     if(data.hasOwnProperty(i) && data[i].indexOf(text) !== -1){
       items[i] = data[i];
     }
   }
   return items;
 }

 console.log(search(data, 'pur'));
```

Try it in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oe9kc8ne/

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over the keys of the object and perform a [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and if found add the property to the result object.

```js
var data = {"100":"Jaipur","101":"Delhi","102":"Raipur","104":"Goa"},
    result = function (data, search) {
        var r = {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
            if (data[k].match(search)) {
                r[k] = data[k];
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, 'pur');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```